# Synchronize x-axis zoom in multiple Highcharts-Vue stock charts

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts, vue-component, vuex

I am using [Highcharts-Vue](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue) and I have multiple `stockChart` charts that I want to synchronize their x-axis zoom. So, when I zoom in one, all the others zoom at the same region.

I am trying to achieve the effect [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZArZM/) and I also follow it as an example. But it is not written in vue.

My logic was to follow the code and in the `afterSetExtremes` events, I could call a vuex function to change the charts state and call `setExtremes` to all the other charts.

I tried to insert `events` in the `xAxis` in the object that contains the data and the options to create a chart. But this is created dynamically on the server and its passed to the front-end as a `json`, so the `afterSetExtremes` function does not work. So, this failed

Then, in my front-end vue I tried this

```
<highcharts 
  :constructor-type="'stockChart'" 
  :options="chart" 
  :callback="chartcallback" 
  @change="chartchange" 
  @click="chartclick" 
  v-on:afterSetExtremes="chartextremes" 
  v-on:zoom="chartzoom" >
</highcharts>
```

and in my script

```
import { mapActions } from 'vuex';   
export default {
    name:'VesselCharts',
    props:['chart'], 
    methods:{
      ...mapActions(['zoomed']),    
      chartcallback(){
        console.log('chartcallback CHART LOADED'); 
      },
      chartchange(){
        console.log('CHART changed'); 
      },
      chartclick(){
        console.log('CHART clicked'); 
      },
      chartextremes(){
        console.log('CHART chartextremes'); 
      },
      chartzoom(){
        console.log('CHART chartzoom'); 
      }

    }
}
```

Except `callback` , all the other functions and events do not work. I dont see any `console.log`. So, this failed too.

I am stack.

How can I catch the zoom event and its xMin xMax and then call `chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(xMin, xMax, true, false);` to all the other charts ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use `Highcharts.addEvent` method and listen to xAxis `afterSetExtremes` event (here EventBus is used to fire custom event called "extremes-changed" catched in the Chart component):

```
export function syncCharts(H) {
  H.addEvent(H.Chart, "load", function(e) {
    var chart = e.target;

    H.addEvent(chart.xAxis[0], "afterSetExtremes", function(e) {
      EventBus.$emit("extremes-changed", {
        min: e.min,
        max: e.max,
        chartId: chart.index
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Note, that this function can be saved to a separate file and initialized when chart component is created. Check demo posted below.

**Demo:**

- https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-jyp7o

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.addEvent%3CT%3E

Comment: Since [callback](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue#chart-callback-parameter) is called when chart is loaded, I tried to simplify things and on my code above I did `<highcharts :constructor-type="'stockChart'" :options="chart" :callback="chartcallback" ></highcharts>` and then in my methods `chartcallback(e){
                console.log('CHART LOADED');              
                let chart = e.target;
                Highcharts.addEvent(chart.xAxis[0], "afterSetExtremes", function(e) {
                  console.log(e); 
                });
            } `

Comment: This is according to your `syncCharts` function. But I get `Cannot read property 'xAxis' of undefined`. What am I missing here? Thanks

Comment: In the chartcallback method `let chart = this` and not  `let chart = e.target`. Check it. And if my answer was helpful and correct please mark it as a correct one, thanks.